# How to use 540x 960 HDPI 9 Patch images for 480x 800 resolution

Tags: android-layout, nine-patch, hdpi

I used the [9 Patch generator online.](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) But when I create resources it creates the HDPI resource as 540x960 pixels. To my knowledge the HDPI resources are usually 480x800 pixels. How can I use the resources correctly.

1. Is there a way to use the 540x960 px image in HDPI for 480x800 px
   also?
2. How do I create a 9 patch resourse of 480x800 px to use it for HDPI
   resolution. Is there any other tool available?

The code used: 
`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Test" >
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/tutorial"
        />
</RelativeLayout>`

The image sample if you see has the sides not filled. I have verified the image is correctly 9 patched .

Comment: You are probably **misusing** your 9 patches. They don't have to be as big as the screen. They are meant to be **stretched** to fit their container size.

Comment: @DerGolem
I have used the following code.

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Test" >
 <ImageView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:src="@drawable/tutorial"
     />
</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0):

Here is your error:

```
android:src="@drawable/tutorial"
```

It has to be

```
android:background="@drawable/tutorial"
```

To be stretched

Also mind that the extension has to be **.9.png**, not **.png**.

---

Side note: `fill_parent` has been **deprecated** (since API LEvel 8).
Please, use `match_parent`, instead.